# XPRESS Mosel - Wrong logical operator

Tags: mosel, xpress-optimizer

I am begginer at Xpress Mosel, i am trying to calculate a surplus = max(0;production-consumption) The production is calculated based on the power installed which is a decision variable.
The model gives me an error : Wrong logical Operator.
Please if anyone can help

Comment: Can you please add your .mos script to your question? Without that it is hard to guess what might go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the maximum of things that involve decision variables, you can use the `fmax` function from the mmxnlp package, see the documentation [here](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mipform/dhtml/secothent_sec_ssecgenctr.html).

A short example for a surplus definition is

```
model Surplus

uses "mmxprs"
uses "mmxnlp"

declarations
 production: mpvar
 consumption: mpvar
end-declarations

surplus := fmax(0.0, production - consumption)
  
minimize(surplus)

end-model
```